# magento . after install onepage-checkout

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I have a error after install onepage-checkout.

```
 Warning: include(/srv/www/vhosts/texxx.com/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkqoc/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /srv/www/vhosts/texxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 189
```

but i don't find any file, named additional.phtml. Is this file important? Can I include this commend?

```
  Warning: include(/srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkqoc/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 189

 Trace:
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(189): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(/srv/ww...', '/srv/www/vhosts...', 189, Array)
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(189): Mage_Core_Block_Template::fetchView()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(225): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(242): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(674): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(516): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(467): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('additional', true)
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/mapple/template/checkqo/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml(42): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('additional')
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(189): include('/srv/www/vhosts...')
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(225): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(242): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(674): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(674): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(516): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(467): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/mapple/template/checkqocpage/qoc3columns.phtml(56): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(189): include('/srv/www/vhosts...')
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(225): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(242): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(674): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(536): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(389): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(168): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->indexAction()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
 /srv/www/vhosts/maoshop.com/httpdocs/index.php(111): Mage::run('', 'store')
 {main}
```

`Error log record number: 1145276105627`

Comment: is onestep checkout extension is third party?

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/one-step-checkout-4908.html)

Recommended it as i got this, that i demanded. All Device Compatible.